# regex wont find a match

Tags: regex

I am trying to pull some info here is my regex

```
<tr>
<td>([^<]+)<i><a href="([^<]+)" title="([^<]+)">([^<]+)<\/a><\/i><sup id="([^<]+)" class="([^<]+)"><a href="([^<]+)"><span>[<\/span>1<span>]<\/span><\/a><\/sup><\/td>
<td><a href="([^<]+)" title="([^<]+)">([^<]+)<\/a><\/td>
<td><a href="([^<]+)" title="([^<]+)">([^<]+)<\/a><\/td>
<td>([^<]+)<\/td>
<td>([^<]+)<\/td>
</tr>
```

here is sample html

```
<tr>
<td><i><a href="/wiki/3Xtreme" title="3Xtreme">3Xtreme</a></i><sup id="cite_ref-18" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-18"><span>[</span>18<span>]</span></a></sup></td>
<td><a href="/wiki/989_Studios" title="989 Studios">989 Studios</a></td>
<td><a href="/wiki/989_Studios" title="989 Studios">989 Studios</a></td>
<td>1999-03-31<sup>NA</sup></td>
<td>NA</td>
</tr>
```

As of now i just want to get the data to find matches.. Can you see any reason why it would not match this?

for all the haters....
I dont care about your options on if i should use regex on html or not.. For this case it will work great. I have one page , the data i need is in a table.  Once i can get the data i will save it to my db and never have to use the regex again..  Soooo  if your comment or answer is about your option on using regex with html.. dont post.

Comment: Your first code is supposed to be a regex ? It would at least need some escaping.

Comment: Maybe your regex engine is confused by the newlines?

Comment: Stop parsing HTML with regular expressions [before it's too late](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1258041).

Comment: is \  not escaping?  i thought i just had to escape / ?

Comment: and why stop?  i just need to get some data that i can throw into a db.. regular expressions should be great for this

Comment: It would help to know the language or text editor being used. Different regex engines have different capabilities.

Comment: Php. And using notepad

Comment: My face my face oh god no no noooo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Second line:

```
<td>([^<]+)<i>
```

cannot hope to match:

```
<td><i>
```

as you put a '+' equivalent to '{1,}' while there is nothing between your tags. Didn't check the rest of your regex, but anyway it can't work.

**Edit:**
Please also correct the `"([^<]+)"` and so on (I hope you see why)... And edit your regex when you correct it.

**Edit 2:**
Seeing as it's quite a disaster (sorry but it's the truth :/): please consider replacing all your ([^<]+) things that won't work for all your cases by a simple [(.*?)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

**Edit 3:**
[ and ] must be escaped. (\d will help you catch numbers)

Comment: perfect!  still a noob at this but what is difference in (.*?)  and ([^<]+)

Comment: Nothing in common, it's well explained in the linked page. But adding a ? to a quantifier makes it "lazy" instead of "greedy". So basically, it will try to catch the smallest string and will move on asap (note: there still can be a comeback). The second will just prevent to catch "<".

Answer (score 1):

```
<span>[<\/span>1<span>]<\/span>
```

Lots of problems here: you must escape the brackets and obviously 1 won't match 18